# CircleCi fails due to gradlew: No such file or directory

Tags: android, circleci

I have a project which I want to build with circleCi : https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/circleci/src/master/

This is my .circleci/config.yml file :

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: circleci/android:api-28-alpha
    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      #      - run:
      #         name: Chmod permissions #if permission for Gradlew Dependencies fail, use this.
      #         command: sudo chmod +x ./gradlew
      - run:
          name: Download Dependencies
          command: ./gradlew androidDependencies
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew lint test
      - store_artifacts: # for display in Artifacts: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/artifacts/ 
          path: app/build/reports
          destination: reports
      - store_test_results: # for display in Test Summary: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/
          path: app/build/test-results
      # See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/deployment-integrations/ for deploy examples
```

I receive following error message in CicleCi when I build:

```
!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
./gradlew androidDependencies
/bin/bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory
Exited with code 127
```

What is the reason of that and how to fix it?

Comment: Try by adding/pushing `/gradle` folder to git in your project.

Comment: @VikalpPatel I am using bitbucket, this folder can't be added. look at the source please : https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/circleci/src/master/

Comment: Do comment `.gradle/`(Line#16) → `#.gradle/` in your `.gitignore`(https://bitbucket.org/ali-rezaei/circleci/src/master/.gitignore). After that push the changes and see whether it's working with CircleCI or not.

Comment: It failed with same error message.

Comment: Can you please post the error message.

Comment: It is posted at the end of question : `/bin/bash: ./gradlew: No such file or directory`

Comment: My bad I read some instead of same in your previous comment; that's the reason I have asked to post the error message.

Comment: you need to add `gradlew` executable to your git sources, as you are calling `./gradlew`, which means it is searching for `gradlew` executable in the root directory. Or either you can move to using `gradle` global installation

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, you were right. I added the files and my build was successful. You can share your answer and I mark it as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./gradlew: No such file or directory` error means that the build script is looking for `gradlew` executable in current directory, which does not exist in your source tree.

There are 2 ways to fix it:

1. Add `gradlew` executable to your sources
2. Migrate to standalone `Gradle` installation usage